# Replacing string in a pandas dataframe which don't match a list with another string

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a function which takes a list of name titles, and if a pandas data frame column (labelled 'Title') doesn't have those titles, replace those strings with "Uncommon" and return new df

eg - `preserved_titles=['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Master.']`
if title is '`Dr.`', it is replaced by '`Uncommon`'

I've tried creating a new data frame from the `preserved_titles` (given list) and joining it to the original dataframe so the other values could be replaced by null. I tried converting the dataframe column (['Title']) into a list of strings and looping through it to replace elements not equal to the `preserved_list`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe looks something like

```
   title
0    Mr.
1    Mr.
2  Miss.
3    Dr.
4  Miss.
```

How about this

```
df.loc[~df['title'].isin(preserved_titles), 'title'] = 'Uncommon'
```

Comment: It replaces the strings, but it replaced everything except for 'Mr.'... so 'Mrs.' was replaced with Uncommon

Comment: It only replaces `Dr.` in my example. You could check your `preserved_titles` list or the values in your title series (`pd.Series.unique()`might help) to make sure you didn't miss on capital letters / trailing dots eventually.